# How can we test iOS apps in iOS 4.0 simulator as well as iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, ios5.1

I am using Snow Leopard for developing iOS Applications. Now I am planning to target iOS 5.1, So I have to upgrade to Lion OS X. But I came to know that iOS versions 3.0 to 4.2 can not be tested in Simulators with Lion OS X.

Is there any other way to test apps in iOS 3.0 to iOS 5.1 simulators in Lion OS X?

Answer (score 1):

If you go Xcode>Preferences>Downloads you can download the iOS <s>4.2</s> 4.3 simulator. Unfortunately you can't test on the iOS 3 simulator. Although it pains me to say it (I have an old device as well as a new one), the vast majority of the market is not on iOS 3, so making it backwards compatible is probably not worth it. If you still want to test it, get yourself an 8 GB iPod Touch 1st Gen from eBay.

Comment: How do I download iOS 4.2 simulator? There is no interface to do that.

Comment: Does it not have an install button?

Comment: I apologize - you can download the 4.3 simulator, not the 4.2 simulator. There is not much difference between the two.